# PHP Form not submitting data, it just reloads page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to submit this form but it just reloads the page with the HTML that was above the $Query code.

The inc/common.php is the PDO Database connection script while inc/header.php is just a place where I store stylesheets.

```
<?php 
ob_start();

require('inc/common.php'); ?>
<?php include_once "inc/header.php"; ?>
 <body class="register-page">
<div class="register-box">
  <div class="register-logo">
    <a href="../../index2.html">Our<b>Pet</b>.net</a>
  </div>
  <div class="register-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Register a new membership</p>
<?php   
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            signupdisabled 
        FROM settings 
    "; 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row['signupdisabled'] == 1) 
    { 
        ?>
        <div class="container" style="width:450px;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center;">
              <a class="alert-link">Registrations are currently disabled by Administrators</a>
            </div>
        </div><?php
    }
    else
    {
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { ?>
                            <div class="container" style="width:450px;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center;">
              <a class="alert-link">Please enter a username.</a>
            </div>
            </div> 
        <?php } die() ?>
         <?php 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { ?>
                            <div class="container" style="width:450px;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center;">
              <a class="alert-link">Please enter a password.</a>
            </div>
            </div> 
        <?php } die() ?>
        <?php 


        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { ?>
            <div class="container" style="width:450px;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center;">
              <a class="alert-link">Invalid eMail Address. Please Try Again.</a>
            </div>
            </div>

        <?php } die() ?>
<?php
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 

            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 


        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { ?>
            <div class="container" style="width:450px;">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center;">
              <a class="alert-link">This username is already in use.</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php } die() ?>
        <?php 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This email address is already registered"); 
        } 

        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO 'users' ( 
                username, 
                fullname, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :fullname, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email 
            ) 
        "; 


        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 


        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':fullname' => $_POST['fullname'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email']     
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        header("Location: login.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 

    } 
    ?> 
    <form role="form" action="register.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name"/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>          
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">    
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="#">terms</a>
            </label>
          </div>                        
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" type="submit">Register</button>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>        

    <a href="login.html" class="text-center">I already have a membership</a>
  </div><!-- /.form-box -->
</div><!-- /.register-box -->
    <?php } ?>

<?php include_once "inc/footer-lr.php"; ?>
```

Could anyone try to help me please?

Comment: Try to create a smaller set of example code that illustrates your problem. It could be useful to include a sample data post that you are trying to post. You can get that output by doing a print_r($_REQUEST); die; at the top of the page before submitting, and posting that along with your question.

Comment: you can add some `echo`s in different sections of your code, before `die();` lines to see exactly what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You're using incorrect [**identifiers**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) for your table name:

```
INSERT INTO 'users' 
            ^     ^
```

being regular quotes.

Either remove them

```
INSERT INTO users
```

or use ticks

```
INSERT INTO `users`
```

- Having used `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` would have signaled the syntax error.

Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Identifier Qualifiers:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Hi this is my common.php before making changes. http://pastebin.com/DzW40XLZ I have tried the error reporting code to the top of my file but no errors are given.

Comment: @Crokom `session_start();` that should be on top of your PHP as the first line. You're presently outputting before header and probably don't know it. So do `<?php session_start(); ?>` then `<?php
 
    $username = "root";....`

Comment: I did that but the data is not being submitted into the table.

Comment: @Crokom did you change or delete the quotes? did you add exceptions? error reporting etc?

Comment: I changed them into ticks and I did all the Changes you mentioned.

Comment: @Crokom something is stopping your script somewhere, and you've a lot of `die();` in there. You need to find out what is stopping it. I suggest you make up a test file with the necessary parts to insert into DB. If it still doesn't work, then the problem is in your db/code somewhere.

Comment: I've tried to make a test file but it won't submit. This is my database structure for reference. http://i.imgur.com/iilGnJD.png

Answer (score 0):

Sup man, i sugest you 2 things.

The first one, is like Egzonr says, try to organize a little bit your code, i mean, you doesn't need to create separated files. But try to keep it clean.

The other thing is, create a another file (just to test, you'll delete it after), and try to run your code, but just with your form (remove all of the rest). if it work, you going to add the other pieces of your script

I hope this is usefull for you.
Thanks